# es6 export const and import includes whole modules in file in build bundle instead of just what i have imported

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules, nuxt.js

I am developing a nuxt app and using unicons for icons.

I have an icons.js file like this [icon file](https://github.com/antonreshetov/vue-unicons/blob/master/src/icons.js)

I have imported just an icon from the icon file like this:

```
import { uniEllipsisH } from '@/helpers/icons'
```

When I analyze my bundle using the following command:

```
yarn build --analyze
```

I get the whole *icons.js* file included in my bundle.

[image: analyze report image]

I assume only imported icon should be included in the bundle.
Totally confused.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have `sideEffects: false`? https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/side-effects/README.md

Answer (score 2):

with *"sideEffects = "false"* in package.json

and exporting it as

```
export const foo = {....}
```

instead of

```
module.exports.foo = {...}
```

solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The example icons file you gave is CommonJS and tree-shaking works for ES Modules only.

You can read more about this and other problems that might prevent tree-shaking to work [here](https://medium.com/@lawliet29/tree-shaking-in-real-world-what-could-go-wrong-b398c2b2ebbb).

Comment: I have replaced all *'module.exports.xyx ='* with *'export const xyz ='*. I still get the same result. Is nuxt default webpack config not configured that way?

Comment: There's the possibility that Babel is transforming es modules to commonJS using preset-env. Try debugging what Babel config nuxt is generating.